# Make 2 AJAX calls on button Click

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project. In my home page, I have a search box with a search button.

When User types a Keyword and Click Search, I need to perform 2 independent search Operations (I am using Elasticseach, so two calls to Elasticsearch).

1. Make a call to SearchItems action method, which will go and get Items from Elasticsearch and returns ItemsPartialView.
2. Make a call to SearchCategory action method which goes and gets categories from Elasticsearch and returns CategoryPartialView.

In my home page, I want to make 2 ajax calls, to these action methods using AJAX, to display the result.

[This Image explains what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z37V.png)

**Question:** Is it possible to make 2 calls to 2 action methods on one event using AJAX?

Comment: Yes, You can try it first code.

Comment: Thanks Asif, so I can just make 2 Ajax calls independently and handle their response... there is nothing special about it...

Comment: Glad. You can call either synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: I though Ajax is only Async

Comment: depend on your need , happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. The only real issue is whether you want the ajax requests to be sent in a certain order (and the usual issues of efficiency of code to avoid repeats, the format of the data returned etc). One way of doing this (where the ajax second call is made after the first completes successfully) is sketched out:

```
<input type="text" id="search-query" value="" />
<button id="test-button">Test Ajax</button>
<div id="ajax-one-result"></div>
<div id="ajax-two-result"></div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("click", "#test-button", function(){
            var qry = $("#search-query").val();
            func1(qry);

            function func1(queryString) {
                var urlOne = "/Path/To/AjaxOne";
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlOne,
                    timeout: 30000,
                    data: { query: queryString },
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                    },
                    success: function (transport) {
                        $("#ajax-one-result").html(transport);

                        func2(transport);
                        console.log("AjaxOne success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, text, error) {
                        console.log("ERROR AjaxOne");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                });

            }

            function func2 (ajaxOneResult) {
                var urlTwo = "/Path/To/AjaxTwo";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: urlTwo,
                    timeout: 30000,
                    data: { query: ajaxOneResult },
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                    },
                    success: function (transport) {
                        $("#ajax-two-result").html(transport);
                        console.log("AjaxTwo success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, text, error) {
                        console.log("ERROR AjaxTwo");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

with Controller Actions:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxOne(string query)
{
    // For testing only
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    var result = "AjaxOne Result: " + query;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxTwo(string query)
{
    // For testing only
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    var result = "AjaxTwo Result: " + query;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```